# App crashes when remote JS debug (Windows- Android-emulator)

Tags: react-native

App crashes when I enable remote JS debug .
Windows->Android>emulator

I changed port 8081 (due to antivirus blocks) to 8088 and also did everything .

Hot JS reload , reload etc, works but when I enable remore JS ,app crashes  saying its unable to load ImportScript .[image]

Comment: Also tried below solution but still issue is same-                                        1.(in project directory) mkdir android/app/src/main/assets
2.react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
3.react-native run-android

Comment: Also updated ip & port in emulator dev settings as 10.0.2.2:8088

Comment: In developer tool logs , below message-GET http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false 403 (Forbidden)

Answer (score 0):

1. Start react-native server on different port "react-native start --port 8088"
2. Customize emulator to use port 8088 - ctrl+M > Dev Settngs > Debug server host & port for device >"10.0.2.2:8088"
3. Enable remote debugging - ctrl+M > Debug JS Remotely

Comment: Followed all these 3 steps but still same issue (See attached error message)

Comment: When I press ctrl + M --> Debug JS Remotely , get error message in console :http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android^&dev=true^&hot=true^&minify=false" error 403